# Trigger function when user clicks back arrow or forward arrow in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, event-listener, popstate

I have a map on my website which allows users to search it for places around the planet. I'm trying to make it dynamic so that the user doesn't have to refresh the page each time they do a search.

So far, this is working fine and I'm using `window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/maps?q=example");` to update the URL each time the user searches something new.

However, when the user clicks the back arrow or forward arrow, the URL changes state to what it was previously, but the map doesn't change because the loadMap(); Javascript function is not being called.

Is there a Javascript event handler that listens for the back arrow/forward arrow so that I can update the map by calling loadMap(); with the query variable stored in the URL?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<input id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" value=""> 

<div class='map'></div>

<script>
    // Uses ajax to get map data from PHP file
    function loadMap(){
        var entityData = {
            query: $("#searchBox").val()
        };
        var entityOptions = {
            url: "https://example.com/load_map.php",
            dataType: "text",
            type: "POST",
            data: { mapData: JSON.stringify( entityData ) }, // Our valid JSON string
            success: function( data, status, xhr ) {
                $(".map").html(data);
            }
        };
        $.ajax( entityOptions );
    }
    
    // When user presses enter, load the map 
    document.getElementById('searchBox').onkeypress = function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13'){
            loadMap();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here is what I'm trying to add:

```
<script>

window.addEventListener(*back arrow*, function(event) {
    var q = *get q variable from URL*;
    $("#searchBox").val() = q;
    loadMap();
}

window.addEventListener(*forward arrow*, function(event) {
    var q = *get q variable from URL*;
    $("#searchBox").val() = q;
    loadMap();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onpopstate

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate